# How to set environment variables for nginx to read?

Tags: django, nginx, environment-variables, virtualenv

Im trying to set my django "SECRET_KEY" in a environment variable.

Im using virtualenv+virtualenvwrapper for environment.

After I typed

```
workon mydomain.com
```

i typed

```
export SECRET_KEY=xxxxxx
```

when I try to do

```
echo $SECRET_KEY
```

I get my value (xxxxxx)

So far so good. But when I try to access my site in a browser (using ngnix and gunicorn) I get an error.

Here is my supervisord script for gunicorn

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory = /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/<PROJECT>/
command=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/bin/gunicorn <PROJECT>.wsgi:application -c /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/<PROJECT>/<APP>/gunicorn_conf.py
user = <USER>
```

Here is my gunicorn_conf.py:

```
bind = "127.0.0.1:8000"
logfile = "/home/<USER>/logs/gunicorn.log"
```

Here is my settings.py:

```
def get_env_variable(var_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s environment variable" % var_name
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
    

SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable("SECRET_KEY")
```

How do I correctly set my environment variable so ngnix can read it?

## Edit: Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 125, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/downloads/django-trunk/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/downloads/django-trunk/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 46, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/downloads/django-trunk/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/downloads/django-trunk/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/downloads/django-trunk/django/conf/__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/downloads/django-trunk/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/<PROJECT>/<APP>/settings/staging.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/<PROJECT>/<APP>/settings/base.py", line 40, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable("SECRET_KEY")
  File "/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/<PROJECT>/<APP>/settings/base.py", line 31, in get_env_variable
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
```

Comment: what is the error you get ? can you show the stack trace ?

Comment: Added the traceback of the error.

Comment: Offtopic , can you bit explain to me ,since I'm trying to pass environment  variable to SSI nginx html file so I can change the value dynamically .

Comment: Save yourself a few headaches, messing with operating system supervisor syntax and use dotenv: https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define environment variable inside of supervisor's config with directive `environment=VAR1=<VAR1>,VAR2=<VAR2>`

Something like that:

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/<PROJECT>/
command=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/bin/gunicorn <PROJECT>.wsgi:application -c      /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/<PROJECT>/<APP>/gunicorn_conf.py
user = <USER>
environment=SECRET_KEY=<SECRET_KEY>
```

Comment: Which version of supervisord do yo use? Environment available since 3.0

Comment: Running Version: 3.0a8-1.1

Comment: It seems like it is the format of my key that is causing the problem. My secret contains characters like `=` `+` `*` `%`, if I remove those characters, and only have normal letters, it works.

Answer (score 0):

> **you could load Environment Variable through a file:**

create your own environment file in your app folder:

```
vim /home/ubuntu/workspace/apps/myapp/envfiles/myenvironment
```

add your environment varibles into that file:

`APP_ENVIRONMENT="dev"`

`SECRET_KEY="mysecret_key"`

> Then load this environment into your gunicorn service file:

```
 sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
```

> Configure your environment file in [Service] blog

```
 [Service]
 ....
 EnvironmentFile=/home/ubuntu/workspace/apps/myapp/envfiles/myenvironment
```

Comment: Erm, no. Don't set the secret key in the system wide environment variable for every user on the system. It's supposed to be a secret.

Comment: Its just example for load the env from file., we can secure file  in our file systems which is part of our app